# What's the best way to implement TCP client in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, tcp, koin

I need to implement some async client in android app for communication with external device. I need this client to start connection with specified socket on different thread and then implement some methods which will be sending data to external device, all this methods need to be asynchronous. What is more I need to have guarentee that Android won't kill my process.

This client needs to be working w Dependency Injection. I would like to create single instance of this client being injected and used across many activities.

What I took into consideration is:

- AsyncTask - heard that it is for only short tasks
- Thread - I am struggling with implementing other methods despite run which will be asnychronous and able to be called
- Service - I can't make it asynchronous
- ServiceIntent - I am not sure if it is the best pick for implemeneting async methods.

I need your suggestions which way would be best with simple explanation why.

Comment: What kind of external device are you talking about? It seems you want a permanent connection. Why?

Comment: `Service - I can't make it asynchronous` Unclear what you mean. Usually one starts a thread in a service.

Comment: I am trying to connect phone to drone which is controlled by TCP server on raspberry. I need to connect the phone with this server.

Comment: Ok. But answer my questions. Do you need a permanent connection?

Comment: Yes, I need permanent connection. Sorry for delay. It is the best way to notificate user about loosing connection. Also loosing connection provides information for server to stay stable and idle.

Comment: Disconnections are difficult to discover. Please do a test (in a loop) to connect, send command, read reply and disconnect. How many can you do in a second? 100 ? Isnt that enough?

Comment: I thought about using TCP client, it is easy to discover disconnection using it. But I still have a problem with creating the class responsible for that. I don't know whether should I use Thread, IntentService, or AsyncTask for a TCP Client which will have a permanent connection(if not it will be reconnecting) and will be able to be injected as a bean to many services, all methods need to be working on a different thread.

Comment: Which TCP client are you referring to,?

Comment: The one I am trying to create. My own class which creates socket and provides communication on that socket with drone. Now I am trying to resolve the problem, because I cannot create it on main thread and I am looking forward for solution what class should I use to inherit from.